# Indent code on a web page like in a code editor?

Tags: javascript, css, pre

Is it possible to wrap indented code on a web page the way it's done in a code editor? See the screenshot comparison below to better understand what I mean:

**`pre-wrap` on a web page:**

[image: screenshot 1]

**Wrapping of indented lines in a code editor:**

[image: screenshot 2]

What I am implying is that the indented lines maintain indentation even after wrapping. This doesn't seem to happen on web pages. Is there a CSS property that does this? (JavaScript would be fine too.)

**NOTE:** I am not talking about code highlighting here. It's about indentation of wrapped lines.

---

If this matters — this is how I am showing code blocks on my web pages:

```
<pre><code>if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
  return $post->post_parent;

} else {
  return false;
}
</code></pre>
```

...and the `white-space: pre-wrap;` style is applied on `pre` tag.

Comment: what do you mean *on a web page*, do you mean in a browser or in your editor?

Comment: You have to wrap the "code" (text) in another container, and indent the container.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson web page => my web page in browser :)

Comment: @RobW All the code is in between the `<pre><code>` tags as shown in the example at the end of the question. So, it's not possible indent wrapped lines specifically without much ado.

Comment: A close vote and a down vote? This is a CSS question. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: It's not possible using pure CSS. Do you allow JavaScript?

Comment: @RobW Yes! I already use JavaScript to highlight code blocks, so a little more JS isn't going to hurt. :)

Comment: @StevenLu It's an elastic layout and manual indentation just wouldn't work.

Comment: @StevenLu is right. Most programmers wold like to turn 'auto-wrap' off and just get an horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @PauloScardine But isn't it difficult to scan & understand code when scrolling horizontally? (As for SO, when there's code that I have to scroll horizontally, I simply copy it into my text editor, that way I am able to understand better—due to proper indentation as shown above)

Comment: @StevenLu `> The way this site (SO) does it is it simply doesn't wrap the lines of code. Makes sense. Is there some problem with that?` Please see my reply to Paulo right above.

Comment: @StevenLu I agree with the original poster here. Some people might want the code to wrap so that they can see more of one line at once. I for one do! Everybody has different opinions.

Comment: @AahanKrish: IMHO auto-wrap make things worse to read. A programmer  choose some particular code formatting for a reason, it can help to express the idea behind it - personally I would rather have a scrollbar than an auto-wrapping breaking the line at the wrong place.

Comment: Where'd my original comment go? Anyway this is really only something I've seen in IDE's and (the best) text editors... It is *probably* going to require some careful text node manipulation to make it work well. I don't think it makes a huge difference but I do agree it would improve somewhat the presentation of code on a site such as SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Algorithm

1. Get the contents of the element, and generate a list of all lines.
2. Use the element to measure the width of a space character.
3. Create a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment) (for optimal performance!).
4. Loop through all lines. For each line:

   - Count the number of preceeding white space.
   - Create a block-level element (such as `<div>`).
   - Set the `marginLeft` (or `paddingLeft`, if you wish) property to the product of the size of a single space and the number of prefixed spaces.
   - Append The contents of the line (left trimmed).
5. Replace the contents of the actual element with the fragment.

### Code (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YPnhX/):

```
/**
 * Auto-indent overflowing lines
 * @author Rob W http://stackoverflow.com/u/938089
 * @param code_elem HTMLCodeElement (or any element containing *plain text*)
 */
function autoindent(code_elem) {
    // Grab the lines
    var textContent = document.textContent === null ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
    var lines = code_elem[textContent].split(/\r?\n/),
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        dummy, space_width, i, prefix_len, line_elem;

    // Calculate the width of white space
    // Assume that inline element inherit styles from parent (<code>)
    dummy = document.createElement('span');
    code_elem.appendChild(dummy);
    // offsetWidth includes padding and border, explicitly override the style:
    dummy.style.cssText = 'border:0;padding:0;';
    dummy[textContent] = ' ';
    space_width = dummy.offsetWidth;
    // Wipe contents
    code_elem.innerHTML = '';

    for (i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        // NOTE: All preceeding white space (including tabs is included)
        prefix_len = /^\s*/.exec(lines[i])[0].length;
        line_elem = fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        line_elem.style.marginLeft = space_width * prefix_len + 'px';
        line_elem[textContent] = lines[i].substring(prefix_len);
    }
    // Finally, append (all elements inside) the fragment:
    code_elem.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

### Browser compatibility

- IE8 + (IE7- doesn't support [`white-space:pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space#Browser_compatibility))
- Chrome 1+
- Firefox 3+
- Safari 3+
- Opera 9+ (previous versions untested)

### Notes

- In this example, I calculated the width of a space (U+0020) character. The similar method is used if you want to calculate different values for other white-space characters.
- Follow-up to the previous note: To account for tabs, you have to take a hard route, which degrades performance. For each line, set the contents of the dummy (appended to `code_elem`!) to the prefixed white space, then calculate the width using `.offsetWidth`.
  Each time, the element is rendered. For hundreds of lines, this method may cause a spike in the CPU usage. Don't ever use tabs to display code in a web page!
- The `autoindent` function assumes that the contents of a element is **plain text**.

Comment: This code works great so far. Do you mind if I dropped a comment here at some point later, if I ever find a bug? (At least until I have a good level of proficiency with JavaScript) — thanks a lot for your time. :-)

Comment: @AahanKrish Remark: When the code is copy-pasted in an IDE, all lines have zero preceeding white space. This should be no problem though, because most IDEs/editors have a "refactor" option which fixs the indention. If not, one can visit online tools, such as http://jsbeautifier.org/ (JS/CSS/HTML) or http://www.phpformatter.com/ (PHP).

Comment: Works like a charme for fluid templates (Typo3) but unfortunately golang is not supported?! :o