# Indentation for javascript based custom code editor

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am making a custom code editor for own created language. So far I have achieved syntax highlighting using javascriprt span class. Now I want to add proper spacing or tab space in front of IF ELSE nested loop. I am not very good with javascript.

Following is the code that I have written till now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <style>
            .code-str { color: #008000; }
            .code-elem{ color: #ff0000;}
            .code-comment { color: #0000FF; }
        </style>



<textarea rows="20" cols="100" type="text" id="text2">Code to test

###IFLISTING:7786###

    replaces

###ENDIFLISTING:7786###


Paste this code in the text area below and see the magic </textarea>

        <textarea rows="20" cols="100" type="text" id="text1"></textarea>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">MAGIC</button>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {



                var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;

                str = str.replace(/###IF(.*?)###/g, '<span class="code-elem"></br> </br>###IF$1### </br></span>'); 
                str = str.replace(/###ENDIF(.*?)###/g, '<span class="code-elem"></br> ###ENDIF$1### </br></span>');
                str = str.replace(/###IFLISTING(.*?)###/g, '<span class="code-str">  ###IFLISTING$1### </span>');
                str = str.replace(/###ENDIFLISTING(.*?)###/g, '<span class="code-str">###ENDIFLISTING$1### </span>');
                str = str.replace(/###VAR(.*?)###/g, '<span class="code-comment"> ###VAR$1### </span>');
                 str = str.replace(/###LISTING(.*?)###/g, '<span class="code-comment">  ###LISTING$1### </span>');

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
            }
        </script>


        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[This is the output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3hAj.png)

Now what I want is that the nested IF ELSE loop should be seen clearly with proper indentation.
I have some rough view in my mind. I think I should use a FOR loop and then use a counter for incrementing the IF and ELSE count. But I don't know exactly how to do it. Can anyone provide me with an idea?

I would be very thankful for the smallest help or suggestion.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562465/indent-code-on-a-web-page-like-in-a-code-editor

Comment: Either add some literal spaces inside the replacement, something like `###IF&nbsp;&nbsp;$1###` or wrap the indented parts in a different span and add a css class to it with like `margin: 4px;`. The global regexp already does the looping. Or just use the dupe link's solution if you want to show the exact spacing the user entered.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, :)
I don't want to add a margin. Actually I wanted spacing mainly for the nested loop. So how will it get to know which IF statement is reached yet? or how much spacing shall be done?
And ###IF&nbsp;&nbsp;$1### this is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to iterate all lines, not only those with matching keywords, and then maintain a *current indentation* which you increase for some keywords and decrease for some other. I would store such indentation influence as a property for each keyword, next to the styling property for them:

```js
const keywords = {
    IF: { style: "code-elem", indent: 4 },
    ENDIF: { style: "code-elem", indent: -4 },
    IFLISTING: { style: "code-str", indent: 4 },
    ENDIFLISTING: { style: "code-str", indent: -4 },
    VAR: { style: "code-comment", indent: 0 },
    LISTING: { style: "code-comment", indent: 0 } 
};

function myFunction() {
    let indent = 0;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text1").value.split(/[\r\n]+/).map(line => {
        const oldIndent = indent;
        line = line.trim().replace(/###([A-Z]+)(.*?)###/g, (m, keyword, arg) => {
            const param = keywords[keyword];
            if (!param) return m;
            indent += param.indent;
            return `<span class="${param.style}">${m}</span>`;
        });
        return "&nbsp;".repeat(Math.min(indent, oldIndent)) + line;
    }).join("<br>");
}
```

```css
.code-str     { color: #080; }
.code-elem    { color: #f00;}
.code-comment { color: #00f; }
```

```html
<textarea rows="15" cols="80" type="text" id="text1">###VAR:837:Single###
###IF:69154!=1###
###IF:69154!=1###
 ###VAR:69154:Single###x
###ENDIF:69154###
    ###VAR:69154:Single###x
###ENDIF:69154###
###VAR:990:Single### battery ###VAR:S301:Single###mAh (###VAR:S302:Single###V) 
###IFLISTING:7785###
       replaces
   ###ENDIFLISTING:7785###
###IFLISTING:7786###
    replaces
###ENDIFLISTING:7786###
</textarea><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">MAGIC</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you sooo very much for your help. This works perfectly fine for me and this is even a better way of writting it. Thanks a lot. :)

Can I contact you in future if I face any kind of problem related to this? I hope I won't have one.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have more questions like this, then just ask them on this site, and you can *ping* me by writing a comment with my name in it, preceded with @.

Comment: Hello, I was wondering that is it possible to add '{' and '}' instead of ###IFLISTING:7785### Since this language is used for CMS, so we can not modify it. But I just want to make it easier for the employees to read it.

Comment: I tried doing it with CSS but it is not possible since I need the number that is in the middle of this IF condition. I know we can do it using regular expressions and Javascript. But I am facing problem with the solution that you have provided. Where exactly can I add a .replace() function in your code?

Comment: I will be thankful to you for your help. I am very new to javascript. Don't know much about it but trying to learn everyday. :)

Comment: What exactly would be the output? Can you point to an example?

Comment: I am facing a new problem now. I want to add autocompletion of code and auto close of tags. For eg: if I write an opening  ###IFLISTING:7785### then the closing   ###ENDIFLISTING:7785### should append like a closing tag. How can I achieve this? The number in the middle is a label number so that would change everytime.

Comment: I suggest you post this as a new question. Don't forget to add the code you are working with, and showing what you have tried to make it work, and where exactly you are stuck.